# A simple php script doesn't work with secured https protocol

Tags: php, .htaccess, session, ssl, https

I've got some issues with my PHP script and SSL certified website.
After I implement a secured https protocol, my PHP session doesn't seem to work anymore.
I added to .htaccess file like in the lines below

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

And my simple two web pages with the script below don't work. The variable count in session doesn't get passed to the second page

session1.php

```
<?php
session_name("MySession"); // replace with whatever makes sense
session_start();


if (!isset($_SESSION['count'])) {
    $_SESSION['count'] = 0; 
} else { 
    $_SESSION['count']++; 
}

echo ' the site was reviewed '.$_SESSION['count'].' times during this session';
$link_address = 'https://iampretty-studio.com/session2.php';

echo "<a href='".$link_address."'>session2.php</a>";
?>
```

session2.php

```
<?php
session_name("MySession"); // replace with whatever makes sense
session_start();


if (!isset($_SESSION['count'])) {
    $_SESSION['count'] = 0; 
} else { 
    $_SESSION['count']++; 
}

echo 'The site was reviewed '.$_SESSION['count'].' times during this session';
$link_address = 'https://iampretty-studio.com/session1.php';

echo "<a href='".$link_address."'>session1.php</a>";
?>
```

It always shows that the site is reviewed 0 times.

My question is, what is wrong, what I'm doing wrong?
Before SSL certified it worked without any problems.

Comment: The php logic is fine on my server with https. Just wondering: what happens if you delete the lines with session_name("MySession");  ?

Comment: Your site doesn't create cookies. Can you show session settings from your `php.ini`file?  You should enable these settings `session.use_cookies=On` and  `session.use_only_cookies=On`

Comment: When I delete the lines with session_name("MySession");  the same

Comment: Ok finaly with the phpinfo and very sofisticated script I did the job and 
session.use_cookies is 1
session.use_only_cookies i 1

Session variable count still = 0

Comment: So cookies have to be created

also in php.ini
Session support  prarameter  = yes

So where is the problem I ask again ?

Answer (score 0):

The problem was a BOM. I don't know why my Dreamweaver editor started to add a BOM to each file when I save each one. Because I had display_errors in php.ini turned off it didn't show anything suspicious. That's all